# Customize error messages in the database with connection

Tags: php, connection

I'm new to PHP, and wanted to make my connection back a custom message without making show those warnings.

But when I add the check nothing happens, my complete code below.

```
<?php
class Connect {

    private $Connect;

    public function Connect() {
        $this->Connection();

        if(connection_aborted() == TRUE) {
            $this->Connection();
        }
    }

    public function Connection() {
        global $Config;

        $this->Connect = new mysqli($Config['mysql']['hostname'], $Config['mysql']['username'], $Config['mysql']['password'], $Config['mysql']['database'], $Config['mysql']['dataport']);

        if($this->Connect == false){
            exit('The connection fails, check config.php');
        }

        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please state your problem again more precisely?

Comment: this line: `if($this->Connect == false){
            exit('The connection fails, check config.php');
        }` wanted to return to msg ! nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different methodes

```
$this->Connect = new mysqli(
  $Config['mysql']['hostname'], 
  $Config['mysql']['username'], 
  $Config['mysql']['password'], $Config['mysql']['database'], 
  $Config['mysql']['dataport']) 
    or die('The connection fails, check config.php');
```

or

```
if (!$this->Connection) {
  die('The connection fails, check config.php');
}
```

I should put the error in the die part too if I was you:

```
die('Connection failed' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Comment: Thank you solved my problem , but what is this `!$link` ? I can not do so ? `if (!$this->Connect) {
  die('The connection fails, check config.php');
}`

Comment: It has to be the connection variable sorry, but I don't understand why you should put this into a class, in a different file ok but why a whole class for just creating a connection (and doing it whole wrong) I should recomment to just create a connection.php with into their the $connection = new mysqli(...) and use <?php require 'connection.php'; ?> in every file.

Comment: I am studying php object-oriented , but you saved me ! as give you reputation points ?